# session start access denied, fail to open phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, session, phpmyadmin, xampp

At first i was trying to do the upload file function and some configuration. However though the `file_upload` is ON, the upload file function is still not working. After I do some configuration according to online tutorials my XAMPP server seems to have problem. These were the error messages when i run php file:

> Warning: session_start():
>   open(/var/folders/_z/rzmc9ysn0r15n2_88d5y5lbh0000gn/T/sess_4ff2e15141e8e599a0617ccafaba00c9,
>   O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/presoft/session_test.php on line
>   4
>
> Warning: session_start(): It is not safe to rely on the system's
>   timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting
>   or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of
>   those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/presoft/session_test.php on line
>   4
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/presoft/session_test.php:2) in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/presoft/session_test.php on line
>   4

I also can't access phpmyadmin and the error is:

> Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log
>   file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that
>   cookies are enabled in your browser.

I'm using Xampp server on Mac OS. 
I already looked into session.save_path and the location is `"Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp"`. Tried `"/tmp"` but still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Give ***read/write*** permissions to your Apache `user` on `temp` directory in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/`.

To know your OS user: open Terminal and use command `whoami`

To know your Apache user: Open `httpd.conf` file in 
 `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf`
and look for 
 `user yourusername` and `Group admin`

Answer (score 0):

Usually this comes from a permission problem with the `session.save_path`; in this case I suggest you check the permissions on `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/` and set them such that the webserver process can read and write files there.